# Here is a puzzle from Permutations and combinations

Tags: combinatorics

How many permutations of 1,2,3,4,5,6 are such that each odd number is next to at least one even number ?

Answer (score 1):

An odd number will have no adjacent even number if it appears on an end next to another odd number, or in the middle sandwiched by the other two odd numbers.

For the first possibility, there are 3 choices of an odd number to put on an end, then 2 choices of another odd number to put beside it, and there are two ends, so this can happen in 12 ways.

For the second possibility, the odd numbers can appear together in 6 ways, and the run can begin in 2 different places. Therefore this can happen in 12 ways.

The total number of permutations for which some odd number has no adjacent even number is thus 24, and so the answer to your question is

6! - 24 = 360 - 12 = 348.

Comment: You have a typo in your last line.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks, fixed it!

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It's a 2 to 1 bijection and should be 360

Answer (score 1):

The above line of thinking is right, but there are two mistakes

1. It is implicitly assumed that one prohibited permutation of odd numbers (say two odd numbers at the beginning) lead to one prohibited sequence. Each prohibited permutation of odd numbers leads to multiple prohibited permutations of 1 to 6. For instance, if you fix the first two to be two particular odd numbers, say 3 and 5, then the remaining four numbers can be permuted in 4! different ways in locations 3 to 6. That is you have 4! prohibited permutations starting with 3 and 5, like the following:-

3 5 1 2 4 6

3 5 1 2 6 4

3 5 1 4 2 6

3 5 1 4 6 2

....

So, 
a) the number of permutations with first two as odd are: 3 * 2 * 4 !
b) the number of permutations with last two as odd are: 3 * 2 * 4 !
c) the number of permutations with locations 2 to 4 as odd are: 3 ! * 3 !
c) the number of permutations with locations 3 to 5 as odd are: 3 ! * 3 !

You sum up the above to get 360. So, the answer is 6! - 360 = 720 - 360 = 360

2. 6 ! is not 360, it is 720

Answer (score 0):

Hint: (1) How many unrestricted permutations are there?  (2) How many permutations are there that don't meet the restriction?  (3) subtract